# Error C2660: function does not take 2 arguments C++

Tags: c++, function, primes

Okay so I'm a beginner at coding in C++ and I was making this prime number finding program when I stumbled across this error. This may not be the best and i am open to feedback. The code below is in correct order and continuous.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

//finds prime numbers using Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm
vector<int> calc_primes(const int max);

int main()
{
    unsigned long long int minValue;
    unsigned long long int maxValue;
    bool Loop = true;
    char chContinue;
    vector<unsigned long long int> primes;

    std::string Path;
    Path = "D:\\Work\\Documents\\prime.txt";

    // TODO: code your application's behavior here.
    while (Loop == true)
    {
        cout << "Enter minimum prime number checking range (__________)" << endl ;
        cin >> minValue;
        cout << "Enter maximum prime number checking range (__________)" << endl ;
        cin >> maxValue;
        if (maxValue <= minValue)
        {
            cout << "Invalid selection" << endl <<endl <<endl <<endl ;
            continue;
        }
```

So this is where it gives me an error

```
        calc_primes(maxValue,primes);
```

It tells me that the function doesn't not take two arguments. However, the declaration clearly states that it needs a unsigned long long int and a vector of unsigned long long int, so I'm not very sure.

```
        //opens file path
        std::ofstream of;
        of.open(Path);

        //writes to file and displays numbers
        for(unsigned long long int i = 0; i < primes.size(); i++)
        {
            if(primes.at(i) != 0)
            {
                cout << primes.at(i) <<"     ";
                of << primes.at(i) << "     ";
            }
        }

        cout << endl <<endl <<endl <<endl ;

        of.close();

        cout << "Continue? (y/n)" << endl ;
        cin >> chContinue;

        if (chContinue == 'y')              {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            if (chContinue == 'n')
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Invalid Selection" << endl << endl ;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

this is the function declaration. Do you think I've made a mistake by putting &primes?

```
void calc_primes(unsigned long long int max, vector<unsigned long long int> &primes)
{
    // fill vector with candidates
    for(unsigned long long int i = 2; i < max; i++)
    {
        primes.push_back(i);
    }

    // for each value in the vector...
    for(unsigned long long int i = 0; i < primes.size(); i++)
    {
        //get the value
        unsigned long long int v = primes[i];

        if (v != 0) 
        {
            //remove all multiples of the value
            unsigned long long int x = i + v;
            while(x < primes.size()) 
            {
                primes[x] = 0;
                x = x + v;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function *declaration*:

```
vector<int> calc_primes(const int max);
```

doesn't match your function *definition*:

```
void calc_primes(unsigned long long int max, vector<unsigned long long int> &primes)
```

These should be identical to achieve desired results.

Comment: Your answer is helpful by watching your answer I get into my mind I didn't declare overloaded function and after declaration, it working.

Comment: @shoaibsabir Great!

Answer (score 2):

Might be this is the reason. 
Here:

```
vector<int> calc_primes(const int max);
```

you declaring it with one parameter

And here you declaring it with 2 parameters :

```
void calc_primes(unsigned long long int max, vector<unsigned long long int> &primes)
```